# Finding DEM/HIllshade sources California

Tags: raster, data, dem, hillshade

Creating watershed maps for schools. I want to color ramp the elevation to show low and high points. What kind of files do I need and where to find them?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [SRTM DEM](http://www.cgiar-csi.org/data/srtm-90m-digital-elevation-database-v4-1) as input and create the color relief + hillshade with [gdaldem](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html). If the file is too big for your purpose, you can also use [ETOPO1](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/global.html).They also provide colored images on this site.

If you are looking for a portal, you can visualize several DEM [here](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/dem/squareCellGrid/map?theme=DDP)

Answer (score 0):

See the discussion here

[Looking for a colormap for SRTM like OCM Landscape](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31201/looking-for-a-colormap-for-srtm-like-ocm-landscape/31253#31253)

about improved color ramps.

Note that you have to edit the color ramp's first column (the elevation divisions) to fit your DEM's highest and lowest elevations. It took me some time to figure it out, but I did manage to get some good-looking color relief maps.